# Filter Multiple Rows based on Value in Dropdown

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to filter multiple rows in a spreadsheet that will output the date and status of an employee whose name is selected in a checkbox.  Here is a screenshot of my sheet:

[image: Spreadsheet]

In the example, when "Tom Thompson" is selected in the dropdown in P3, the dates and values (associated with that date) that do not start with the string "Here" would need to appear in R4:S.  I have started with this formula:  `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:M,A2:A=P3))`, and that gives me every value (not the dates and cells starting with "Here" are not filtered out of the results) in a single column.
I am not sure where to go from there.  Also, not sure how to transpose it and run a query off of the results.  The column number itself would be unknown.  It would be based on the value of P3.  Hope I was clear.  Contact me for further clarification if necessary.

**Edit:**  Would appreciate some feedback as to what is wrong or unclear in the post, so I can phrase questions better in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,transpose({B1:M1;filter(B:M,A:A=P3)}),
       filter(Σ,index(Σ,,2)<>"Here"))
```

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you.  Wish I understood the formula.  Wil have to do some studying up...

Comment: Try this part separately first `transpose({B1:M1;filter(B:M,A:A=P3)})` and then in the second step I am using filter to extract all rows when second column `index(Σ,,2)` does not contain the `Here` word.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Very helpful in regard to understanding what is happening here.